# Mendeley always crashes on startup?

Tags: crash, desktop-computer, mendeley

Mendeley desktop always crashes on startup.  The application has to repair the local database and send a crash report.  Then it turns of watched folders.  I am using Mendeley beta 0.9.9.2. on Windows 7.  It is very frustrating as it happens every day.  Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem apparent what the issue may be, based on your description, however I'd suggest contacting Mendeley's support team with your problem. They should have the error report and should be able to help you sort that out quickly. Here's the link to their [support form](http://www.mendeley.com/contact-support/).
Be sure to provide as much info as possible like operating system, versions, etc.

Hope you get that sorted out soon!

Comment: I have contacted them repeatedly but with no luck.  Thought someone might have the same issue.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You have had no reply to your inquiries? I'd either try their [Feedback forum](http://feedback.mendeley.com) or drop them another email. There's a new dev preview available for download. Might want to try that too. Might have fixed you issue.

Comment: I have come to hate this product. I am trying to finish my phd and spend hours battling with Mendeley. I spent half a day manually deleting corrupted content. I also pay for it.

Comment: This is quite strange behaviour. Sorry to read this. I'm using it for my PhD and have never run into issues. In fact, every update has made it faster and more reliable. I'd like to help you make it a more pleasant experience. Perhaps contact support@mendeley.com and I'll have them keep an eye our for your username. It's supposed to make life easier, not more difficult!

Comment: Long ago I had similar issue once. And right now I am having the same issue. I cannot open Mendeley for 4 hours, every time I open it crashes. I am using 1.17.13 which is latest of this time. The only solution that works is to reset and download all documents again.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Mendeley ***beta*** 0.9.9.2. Try downloading a version of Mendeley that isn't Beta.
Uninstall your current version of Mendeley and download the non-Beta version available at [Mendeley's website](http://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/). As of writing this answer, the current version available for download at that website is version 1.9.2. If you still have problems after changing the version of Mendeley which you are using, please comment on this answer or post a new question on this site.

Here's a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Beta) explanation about beta-released software:

> Software in the beta phase will generally have many more bugs in it than completed software, as well as speed/performance issues and may still cause crashes or data loss. The focus of beta testing is reducing impacts to users, often incorporating usability testing. The process of delivering a beta version to the users is called beta release and this is typically the first time that the software is available outside of the organization that developed it.